# PHP/mySQL game point system

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a web application/game using PHP and mySQL. I need to give the users/players an amount of *points* on a certain interval of time.
What is the best method to do this? (my ideea is when the log in i verify hist last_login and add the number of *points* that he would have gained in that period)
What other way is to this? (maybe timed triggers...)

Comment: does the user get to see how many points they have while they're offline? if you only do the update at login, they won't see any points show up until they do log in, then suddenly a bunch magically show up.

Comment: Not sure if it as good idea but you can use setInterval of javascript and make AJAX requests to add points. They will get points only if they are connected.

Comment: that is not sure for now... so i prefer that the users can see the points offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a php script that adds points to the appropriate column in the database, and call the script using a cron job at fixed time intervals.

Comment: This is probably your best bet.  Keep in mind that for some multi-user games, you may want users to be able to see each others scores (not sure if that is the case for you), or you may want to trigger emails to user on reaching certain scores (to help drive interaction).  If you are waiting for the user to login, you will not have any of the potential functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your point of how it should work is correct if we are talking about scripting languages such as PHP/Python/Ruby/etc. But don't forget about internal interaction when you should have actual value of `user points`. To handle with this you can create some trigger (I don't mean SQL trigger - it should be done according to your architecture design) on `points data` load.